# Romantic manga with time-traveling police officer

Tags: story-identification, time-travel, manga

The story is about a young woman, working as a police officer or something. She is in love with a fellow colleague. While visiting her old high school she meets a wanted criminal. Said criminal was about to commit suicide by jumping of a building. The main heroin wanted to prevent this, but falls with him.

Instead of dying she somehow travels back in time into her younger self back in high school. There she meets this criminal, who still hasn't committed any crimes. She now wants to "re-educate" him, so that he won't end up the same as his future self. Meanwhile they fall in love with each other.

Her previous crush from the future somehow ended up in the past as well and they collaborate together to save the "criminal".

I remember reading this manga back in 2017. Back then it was still ongoing.

Comment: Hi there! :) Could you take a look at [this guide on how to ask a good story-id question](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/98028), see if that triggers any more memories you could [edit] in? For instance, when did you read that? We're there multiple issues or was it a one-shot? Tuff like that, to increase the chances of a successful identification. Cheers!

Answer (score 4):

This is [*The Country Is Saved!*](https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/the-country-is-saved) (2011 - 2013).

> A 28-year-old female prosecutor Min-seo is just about to go out with Jun-hyun, a good looking prosecutor whom she has had a crush on since high school. With a successful career and her soon-to-be boyfriend, it seems like she is the happiest woman in the world. However, she suddenly time travels to her high school life while she is chasing a male suspect named Sang-woo; he was a senior in her high school. She genuinely does not want to revive her high school life because it was just the stereotype of a nerd. With a strict moral code as a prosecutor, a teenager’s appearance, and two attractive men, namely Jun-hyun and Sang-woo, around her, her second high school life will be nothing like her previous one.

Comment: Could you explain how this matches the description?

Comment: I'm not sure why you deleted this. It seems to be a helpful answer to the question posted.