# Manga where a women who is a prosecutor tries to save a criminal from committing suicide and goes back in time to high school there she could save him

Tags: story-identification, manga

Recently I was looking for this manga that I forgot the name of. I remember  that it was a woman who worked for the government and she ends up at her old high school and sees a man about to commit suicide she tries to help him but ends up falling off the roof with him and somehow gets sent back in time she’ll then have to repeat high school but in the process she will  try to save the man from  the life of crime.

Comment: The text of this is almost identical to [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/193663/76048) from eighteen months ago (which I notice you have also posted an answer to).

Comment: I’m am not the same user. I was looking for the same manga nobody had answered her question so I decided to ask again than I found it on my own and decided to answer her question

Answer (score 0):

I found the manga I was looking for. 
The name of it is [*The Country is Saved!*](https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/the-country-is-saved)

> A 28-year-old female prosecutor Min-seo is just about to go out with Jun-hyun, a good looking prosecutor whom she has had a crush on since high school. With a successful career and her soon-to-be boyfriend, it seems like she is the happiest woman in the world. However, she suddenly time travels to her high school life while she is chasing a male suspect named Sang-woo; he was a senior in her high school. She genuinely does not want to revive her high school life because it was just the stereotype of a nerd. With a strict moral code as a prosecutor, a teenager’s appearance, and two attractive men, namely Jun-hyun and Sang-woo, around her, her second high school life will be nothing like her previous one.